# Problem on converting HSI to RGB color space and vice versa

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing, rgb

I'm trying to implement color complement image processing , since opencv doesnt have rgb to hsi color conversion , i have to do that myself , unfortunately i found a problem.

here's a piece of code where i try to convert rgb to hsi

```
for( i = 0 ; i < src.rows ; i++){
for( j = 0 ; j < src.cols ; j++){
  var pixel = src.ucharPtr(i,j);
  r = pixel[0];
  g = pixel[1];
  b = pixel[2];


  intensity = (b+g+r)/3;
  var min_val = Math.min(r,g,b);
  s = 1 - 3*(min_val/(b + g + r));
  if(s < 0.00001)
    {
          s = 0;
    }else if(s > 0.99999){
          s = 1;
    }

  if(s != 0)
  {
    h = 0.5 * ((r - g) + (r - b)) / Math.sqrt(((r - g)*(r - g)) + ((r - b)*(g - b)));
    h = Math.acos(h);


    if(b <= g)
      {
        h = h;
      } else{
        h = 360 - h;
      }
  }

  pixel[0] = h;
  pixel[1] = s;
  pixel[2] = intensity;
```

and here's the code where i try to convert it back to rgb

```
for(i = 0 ; i < src.rows ; i++){
for(j = 0 ; j < src.cols ; j++){
  var pixel = src.ucharPtr(i,j);
  h = pixel[0];
  s = pixel[1];
  intensity = pixel[2];
  if(h < 120){
    b = intensity*(1-s);
    r=intensity*((1.0+((s*Math.cos(h))/(Math.cos(60-h)))));
    g=1-(r+b);
  }
  else if(h < 240){
    h -= 120;
    r=intensity*(1-s);
    g=intensity*((1.0+((s*Math.cos(h))/(Math.cos(60-h)))));
    b=1-(r+g);
  }
  else{
  h=h-240;
  g=intensity*(1-s);
  b=intensity*((1.0+((s*Math.cos(h))/(Math.cos(60-h)))));
  r=1-(g+b);

  }
  pixel[0] = r;
  pixel[1] = g;
  pixel[2] = b;

}
```

}

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C194g.jpg)

[HSI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1mtH.png)

[Reverse Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unl0r.png)

I just followed the RBGtoHSI algorithm and vice versa. am i doing that the right way or there are something i missed ?

Thanks !

Comment: You have `pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2]` as `r, g, b` respectively. However if this image was read with OpenCV, then the image will actually be in `b, g, r` order (which is the OpenCV default). You didn't show how you're reading your image, so not sure if that's what the problem is---either way, a good first thing to check.

Comment: Remember you can't fit 360 degrees of Hue into an unsigned char - because that has a range of 0-255. OpenCV uses a granularity of 2 degrees so that the full 360 degrees are mapped to 180 degrees which can then fit into an unsigned char...